# Not Permitted - adding Yahoo Mail as a pop3 account to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail, pop3

I intend to add my *Yahoo Mail* account as a *pop3 account* to my old *Gmail*.

In `GMail > Settings > Accounts & Import > Add a POP3 mail account you own`. 
I mentionned my Yahoo account settings but I got the following **error message** :

```
Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
Server returned error: "[AUTH] Access to this service is not permitted."
```

Any idea ? Why it is not **permitted** ? is Google & Yahoo not permitting stuffs like that anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo doesn't allow for POP access without their premium services. They do however offer it if you sign up for Yahoo Plus services.

[**Yahoo! Mail Plus**](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_ML&locale=en_US&id=SLN3422&impressions=true)

Comment: If you live in certain countries and time zones outside the US, there are yahoo mail versions that allow POP email.